# Convert Text file to XML

Tags: c#

I need to convert text file to XML file through C# application. Can any one provide me sample code.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Comment: It might also be nice to define what rules govern the conversion you seek.  Is slapping a high level tag around the text sufficient, or are you trying to do something more granular?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have not provided enough information to receive an answer.

What format is the text file?
What kind of XML do you want?

Unless you provide more information, here is the correct answer:

```
File.Move(@"C:\File.txt", @"C:\File.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
File.Move("CurrentFileDirectory","NewFileDirectory");

CurrentFileDirectory = @"C:\Documents\YourFile.Text";

NewFileDirectory = @"c:\Documents\Yourfile.XML";
```